# Angular directive query sibling HTML

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-lifecycle-hooks, angular10

Using Angular 10 I want to query a sibling element.  Essentially I have something like this:

```html
<label myDirective for="foo" ...
<input id="foo" formControlName="xyz" ...
```

In `myDirective` I can easily get the value of `for` via a `@HostBinding`. In my directive I then  want to get the `formControlName` of the element with the given ID.  I'm not sure how to do that because it seems like my directive might run before the input element has been created, for example.

I'm trying to automate a bit so I don't have to write this:

```html
<label [myDirective]="foo.attributes.getNamedItem('formControlName').value" ...
<html #foo ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `@Input()` inside your directive code. Your directive:

```
  @Input() for;

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!!this.for) {
      console.log(this.for.attributes.formcontrolname.nodeValue); // name
    }
  }
```

Your HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div appDirective [for]="any"> 
  <input #any formControlName="name">
  </div>
</form>
```

That way you have the `formControlName` attribute you asked for. To get its value, I don't see a way not inputing the form too. Or you can access the `this.for.value`. But you must be careful because this will take the native element input value.

Comment: Thank you.  I did it in `ngOnInit` instead of `ngOnChanges` and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Awesome! Just be careful using it on `ngOnInit`, if you`*ngIf` your input, it will be an `undefined`. A fair warning.